# How to add a shell output content to vim?

Tags: vim, shell, vi

When using vim, we can use `:!ls` to execute shell command, but how can we import the `ls` output into vim for editing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See "`:help :read!`".  For example:

```
:read !ls
```